# What' s the difference between <= and := in VHDL

Tags: embedded, logic, vhdl, colon-equals

Currently, I am learning some FPGA design techniques using VHDL, my problem is whether we can use := and <= interchangeably in VHDL or not, though I've seen the use of := in constants declarations and <= in assignments? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The rules are a little more complex than this, but basically: you use `<=` to do signal assignment, which takes effect on the next delta cycle. You use `:=` to do variable assignment, which takes place immediately. So if you have a signal, you always use `<=`. If you have a variable, you always use `:=`.

Some places where this is not quite that case that you will commonly run into, for instance, initialization, where `:=` is used even for signals.

So:

```
signal some_signal : std_logic := '0'; -- 0 initial value
...
variable some_variable : std_logic := '0'; -- 0 initial value
...
some_signal <= '1'; -- will assign 1 at the next time step (delta cycle)
...
some_variable := '1'; -- assigns 1 immediately
```

Comment: you mean I can use these two symbols interchangeably or there are some exceptions? @wjl

Comment: `<=` is for signals, `:=` is for variables, except for initial values that both use `:=`

Comment: For information on delta cycles, check out this good article on the subject: http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel

Answer (score 4):

if you use ***signal temp:std_logic_vector*** then you'll have to use **<=**

if you use ***variable temp:std_logic_vector*** then you'll have to use **:=**

Answer (score 0):

`<=`

**UseCase**: **Signal** assignments that take place in the next cycle.

**Example**: `signal temp:std_logic_vector`

`:=`

**UseCase**: **Variable** assignments that take place immediately.

**Example**: `variable temp:std_logic_vector`

---

Except for adding initial values to signals, you can also use `:=`.